# Amazon EC2 ssh operation times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an ec2 host from January this year which was working fine. But recently I saw that my java app there was not responding and hence I tried to ssh to my ec2 host with the `.pem` key. Although, `ssh 22` port is allowed for all in the security group, yet it times out.

I cannot lose the data in the mysql server that lives there. So I tried to add a rule to open `3306` port and access externally to that server. But that times out too. Double checked the security groups. They seems to be okay. Here's the screenshot of my security groups.

[image: Security groups]

Then, I took an image of the instance and created another instance from that image. Guess what, I cannot ssh to that host either.

Then, just to assure myself, I created another instance but this time a fresh one i.e. not from the image. I can easily ssh into my host.

What am I missing here? Or what's the problem with my previous host? I've already search for the answer in SO and none could help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Check the security group rules

Comment: As I've already told in the question. I've checked the security groups and found okay.

Comment: May be SSH is disabled in your host

Comment: Whats the error when try SSH ??

Comment: `May be SSH is disabled in your host` - Hopefully its not. I've already rebooted the server which should enable the ssh if it was disabled. `Whats the error when try SSH ??` - Operation timed out.

Comment: Can you check the IP address of the security groups of that host its allowed to all IP or a specific IP

Comment: Its allowed to all IP addresses.

Comment: Is it possible to update the question with security group screenshot??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152595/discussion-between-reaz-murshed-and-jabaa).

Comment: Post the output with verbose option `ssh -v .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dmohr's answer was not an exact solution but helped me a lot. However, my aws guru [@leapoffaith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132275/leap-of-faith) managed to recover the data for me using the following steps. He provided me the steps he followed later and then I thought of posting these here as well as I found these useful for other developers who might face the same issue like me.

1. Get a new ec2 instance.
2. Stop the corrupted ec2, detach it’s EBS volume, attach the volume to the new instance.
3. Then mount the volume with your newly created EC2 instance. Use the following commands to mount :

   - Make a new mount point : `mkdir mount_point`
   - To mount : `sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 mount_point/`  (note that the device name can be different).
4. Get permission of the previous mysql data:
   `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) mount_point/var/lib/mysql`
5. Install mysql in the new ec2 host :

   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` - Remember to use the same root password that you used to connect to your mysql database from your server application.
   - `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
6. Stop mysql service : `sudo service mysql stop`
7. Copy your database folder from the mount_point’s mysql folder to `/var/lib/mysql` folder. For example, `sudo cp -r yourdb /var/lib/mysql/`
8. If InnoDB Engine,

   - `sudo cp ibdata1 /var/lib/mysql/`
   - `sudo cp ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/`
   - `sudo cp ib_logfile1 /var/lib/mysql/`
9. Give ‘mysql’ user permission :

   - `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql yourdb/`
   - `sudo chmod -R 777 mysql/yourdb`
10. Start mysql service : `sudo service mysql start`
11. Unmount the EBS : `sudo umount -d /dev/xvdf1`

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a fresh instance, then stop your old instance, detach the volume, attach the volume to your new instance and mount the volume. Then at least you would have access to the drive and could save your mysql data.

Comment: This is not exactly the solution to my problem. But anyway, this solved the problem of getting my mysql data back. Up-voted with thanks!